# Event is not responding properly

Tags: 8, rules

I created 2 rules with the same action, which sends Drupal logs to the site. One is *Content is created* with the *After saving new content (rules_entity_insert:node)* event; the other one is *Content is updated* with the *After updating content (rules_entity_update:node)* event. Also, they use the same *Condition: Node is of type* condition.

I am using a REST request to create/edit a node. However, when I do a POST, I am getting 2 logs in the site, which means that both rules are being triggered. PATCHing a node is working fine: A single log is created.

Am I missing something?

I am using the Rules module 8.x-3.0-alpha3. The action is programatically created.

Comment: To rule out that the REST POST request is doing something strange when creating a node, I assume that you have tested creating content manually - using the normal Drupal node creation form? It is also helpful if you add which version of Rules you are using.

Comment: the result is the same when creating the content from web. Already added the rules version.

Comment: If 8.x-3.0-alpha3 (May 2017) really is the version you are using, then I suggest updating to rules 8.x-3.0-alpha4 (May 2018). Still the same problem? If so, check the Rules issue queue ;-)

Comment: I did update into alpha4, still no luck.

Comment: So it looks like a bug then. Search the issue queue - and maybe post a new issue?

Comment: yes, I already posted same concern on the issue list of Rules

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2990211#comment-12716081

> I have another rule that modify the title of my node with event
>   **After updating content (rules_entity_update:node)**. But since that rule is necessary, then it should not be deleted but still I dont want
>   to get a duplicate result when a node is created. So what I did, is I
>   change the other rule that modifies the title into event **Before
>   saving content (rules_entity_presave:node)** so it wont be called on
>   node creation, and this works!